# React Native - can't close console log and bottom tab navigator have a one step delay

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

After update xcode to 9.2 (newest possible on my current mbp) I can't close console log (when i click it shows the highlight looks like I'm keep pressing this button) when i try to scroll screen on the app then it dissappear. Second problem is when I'm trying to navigate through bottom tab navigator it gives me one click delay - in example when i click Tab1 it doesn't show me Tab1 screen but when later I'll click Tab2 it shows me Tab1  - I've build it also on my iPhone 8 and it's working correcly on physical device. Before update to new xcode it also work correct on the simulator - there was no changes in the code. I've tried to

Xcode -> product -> clean,
Xcode -> product -> clean build folder,
rebuild whole app,
move code to the new react native app,
run on multiple simulators (iphone 7,8,X)(iosx 10.3, ios 11.2)
simulator -> erase all content and settings

Versions:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.1
react-navigation: 3.2.0
xcode 9.2
Mac os sierra 10.12.6